# authenticate user using R googlesheets timeout

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

I want to authenticate a user using R `googlesheet`. I tried using:

```
library(magrittr)
library(googlesheets)

suppressMessages(gs_auth(token = "...\\Documents\\googlesheets_token.rds", verbose = FALSE))
```

but I obtain the next message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>   Timeout was reached: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds

I want to change the timeout to 400000 milliseconds, does anyone have one idea?

Comment: I didn't find the anwser so I used Python with the modules gspread and oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find the solution for this qustion I make the project in Python Using

```
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
```